# Length of all sides of a triangle, knowing one angle one length and the perimeter of the triangle.

Tags: trigonometry

i am sure this question is answered in a round about way, but my math is not strong enough to put it all together so i need a direct answer for my direct question if you don't mind (:

Now i did draw a nice easy to read image for this, but because i am a noob it would not let me post an image!. so i have attempted to use text to represent the problem. Sorry if its a bit strange!  NOTE all line are straight. even if i cant draw them that way.

[image]

the length of a, b and c are know, they form an equilateral triangle so the internal angles are also known.

the total length of d and e together is known as f.

the length of d and e on their own is not known.

e is a continuation of c.

with A + F you know the total perimeter of the larger triangle.

I need to know what the length of e is.

Is this even possible? and if so how can it be calculated?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By cosine rule we have:
$$ d^2 = a^2 + (c+e)^2 -2a(c+e)\cos(B)$$

and we have

$$d = f-e$$

So, 
$$ (f-e)^2 = a^2 +(c+e)^2-2a(c+e)\cos(\pi/3)$$
$$ (f-e)^2 = a^2 +(c+e)^2-a(c+e)$$

$$ f^2 +e^2-2fe=a^2+c^2+e^2+2ce-ac-ae$$
fortunately $e^2$ terms can be omitted:
$$ f^2 = e(2f + 2c-a) -ac +a^2+c^2$$
and final result:
$$e = \frac{f^2-a^2-c^2+ac}{2f+2c-a}$$

Comment: Thanks for the very quick answer.  I was hoping it would be simpler to solve as I need to calculate the answer on a low powered micro controller.   I guess I will have to write the code and see how fast it is.

Comment: I think you must use some numerical method. Take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots).

Comment: No. You have the $a^2$ and $ d^2$ terms in your first equation mixed up.

Comment: Thanks user153245. i had a quick look at the link but its going to take me a while to digest that. as i said my math is not all that strong.  I was hoping the answer would be more in the form e = blar blar blar. i am not even 100% sure how to convert the above answer into code. Having said that i do intend to have a good go, and if it works then i will choose this answer as the correct one.

Comment: @user254665, you're right. I corrected it.

Comment: You have a typo in the denominator of the last line: "e" should be "c". Why is my answer below not equal to yours?

Comment: Let a=b=c=3, d=4,and c+e=5, so the figure is a right triangle and e=2 and f=6.but your formula  without the typo gives e=9/5......

Comment: @user254665 I think there is not any such triangle!, Because as you know in a 30-60-90 triangle (the biggest one in the figure) the side opposite the 30 degree angle must be half the hypotenuse. But in your hypothesis triangle, it is 3 and the hypotenuse is 5 (= 3+2).

Comment: Thanks very much user153245,  I have done a few tests and it seems to work fine!.  plus the final equation is not all the difficult to calculate so it should be fast enough for me to calculate on my micro controller.